# Exponential upper matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider the matrix

$M = \left[ \begin{matrix} A & v \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right] \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1)\times(n+1)},$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Compute the [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) $e^{M}$ ( $= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} M^k/k! $ ).

Comment: I think $e^{M}$ is of the form $\left[ \begin{matrix} e^A & * \\ 0 & I \end{matrix} \right]$, but I am not sure about the vector $*$ in position $(1,2)$.

Comment: The star is equal to $e^{Av}$. If you know the matrix M, in oreder to compute that powers you should use eigenvalues and diagonalization.

Comment: @SebiSebi:  I think you might want to write $e^A v$.

Comment: So $* = e^A v$?

Comment: Yep. Sorry! It's $e^{A}v$

Comment: I thought there is some factor $1/2$ or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
M^{k}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A^{k} & A^{k-1}v\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
for $k\geq1$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
e^{M} & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}M^{k}/k!\\
 & =I+\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A & v\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A^{2} & Av\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]/2+\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A^{3} & A^{2}v\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]/6+\ldots\\
 & =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
e^{A} & \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}A^{k-1}/k!\right)v\\
0 & I
\end{array}\right]\\
 & =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
e^{A} & \left(e^{A}-I\right)A^{-1}v\\
0 & I
\end{array}\right]\text{ (assuming }A\text{ is nonsingular)}
\end{align*}